# Finding data type with query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to find which fields are of CLOB data type in table with SQL query?
I had tried the below query to fetch the data type but it is giving me error:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Please suggest!!!

```
SELECT  data_type
FROM    SYS.COLUMNS
WHERE   OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('PS_P1_EPA_EMPLOYEE');
```

Answer (score 4):

The data dictionary for Oracle isn't the same as for other RDBMS. If this is your own schema:

```
select data_type
from user_tab_columns
where column_name = 'PS_P1_EPA_EMPLOYEE'
```

... although that looks more like a table name, so maybe:

```
select column_name, data_type
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'PS_P1_EPA_EMPLOYEE'
```

You can also restrict on `data_type ='CLOB'`.

If it isn't in your schema, you can look in `all_tab_colmns` or `dba_tab_columns`. Documentation for all three views is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10820/statviews_2103.htm).